# Setting up custom Adapter for Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I am currently working on a project that will keep track of player scores and other information for a game called Farkle. I have done about 100 Google searches and read several entries on here as well. I have tried implementing and using everything I have found, but I am just at ends here.

The **row.xml** will be loaded as a single item in a `ListView`.

Ultimately, I want to have in order (you will see my row.xml layout below): 
"Player's name" checkbox checkbox "Player's score".

I can get the app to run, so I don't have an issue at launch, however, as soon as I attempt to add a new player, the app breaks.

Now, the code I have below is a new project, as the last one had broken to a point that it showed no errors but would crash on launch. I have tried using a custom `ArrayAdapter`, and I believe this is the method that will work for me, but I just cannot seem to get it to load the row.xml without crashing. I am still new to the ArrayAdapter, and I have done a few tutorials, but I still can't get it worked.

If anyone has any ideas as to what I can do to get this worked, please help and get me pointed in the right direction. I have been working on this for 2 weeks now! Thank you in advance.

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSetScore"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/winning_score" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddPlayer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/add_player"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSetPenalty"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/set_penalty"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvScoreBoard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStatistics"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/statistics" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNewGame"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_game" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my **row.xml**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPlayer"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/player"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbFarkle1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbFarkle2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScore"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/player_score"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

String winningScore = "";
String playerName = "";
String playerScore = "";
String farklePenalty = "";
int penalty;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creates Buttons
    final Button btnSetScore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetScore);
    Button btnAddPlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddPlayer);
    final Button btnSetPenalty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetPenalty);
    Button btnStatistics = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStatistics);
    Button btnNewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewGame);

    // Creates ListView for player score board
    final ListView lvScoreBoard = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvScoreBoard);

    // Sets the game winning score when the Set Score button is pressed.
    btnSetScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Set Winning Score");

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    winningScore = input.getText().toString();
                    btnSetScore.setText(winningScore);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
                    dialog.cancel();        
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
                }

            });

            builder.show();

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        }
    });

    // Adds a new player to the game when Add Player button is pressed.
    btnAddPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Player");

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    playerName = input.getText().toString();



                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
                    dialog.cancel();        
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
                }

            });

            builder.show();

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        }
    });

    // Sets the third farkle penalty when Set Penalty button is pressed.
    btnSetPenalty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Set Farkle Penalty");

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    farklePenalty = input.getText().toString();
                    penalty = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                    btnSetPenalty.setText(farklePenalty);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
                    dialog.cancel();        
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
                }

            });

            builder.show();

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        }
    });

    // Changes to statistics activity when Statistics button is pressed.
    btnStatistics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    // Resets all data when New Game button is pressed.
    // This will also have the ability to keep player names, 
    // but erase farkle counts, player scores, penalty, 
    // and winning score.
    btnNewGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Customed ListAdapter, but I know it is wrong.

```
public class GeneralAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final CharSequence Name = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
private ArrayList<String> info = null;

public GeneralAdapter( ArrayList<String> info) {
    this.info = info;
}

String name;
String score = "0";
boolean farkle1 = false;
boolean farkle2 = false;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return info.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return info.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.generalTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayer);
        holder.generalCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbFarkle1);
        holder.generalCB2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbFarkle2);
        holder.generalTV2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvScore);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.generalTV.setText(name);
    holder.generalCB.setChecked(farkle1);
    holder.generalCB2.setChecked(farkle2);
    holder.generalTV2.setText(score);

    return null;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView generalTV;
    TextView generalTV2;
    CheckBox generalCB;
    CheckBox generalCB2;
}
```

}

Comment: You should post the crash log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crash log or at least the exception you're encountering would help.

That said, I can see one issue. You're returning null from getView(). Try returning convertView instead:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.generalTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayer);
        holder.generalCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbFarkle1);
        holder.generalCB2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbFarkle2);
        holder.generalTV2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvScore);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.generalTV.setText(name);
    holder.generalCB.setChecked(farkle1);
    holder.generalCB2.setChecked(farkle2);
    holder.generalTV2.setText(score);

    return convertView;  // HERE!!
}
```

Also, you may want to do some null checking when you grab holder from convertView. If, for some reason, that ends up being null, then the first thing referenced from it would cause a NRE. I can't see anything wrong from your code, but since you're running into crashes, it's worth a try.

---

Taking a step back, you're never using info from within the adapter. In other words, every list item will look exactly the same because they're using the same values (name, farkle1, farkle2, score).

Perhaps you mean to have an array of objects that have those members on them? Something like so:

```
public class DataItem {
    String name;
    String score = "0";
    boolean farkle1 = false;
    boolean farkle2 = false;
}
```

An then pass that into your adapter, something like this.. (Note: I haven't tried to compile )

```
public class GeneralAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final CharSequence Name = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
private ArrayList<DataItem> info = null;

public GeneralAdapter( ArrayList<DataItem> info) {
    this.info = info;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return info.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return info.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    DataItem dataItem = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.generalTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayer);
        holder.generalCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbFarkle1);
        holder.generalCB2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbFarkle2);
        holder.generalTV2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvScore);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.generalTV.setText(dataItem.name);
    holder.generalCB.setChecked(dataItem.farkle1);
    holder.generalCB2.setChecked(dataItem.farkle2);
    holder.generalTV2.setText(dataItem.score);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView generalTV;
    TextView generalTV2;
    CheckBox generalCB;
    CheckBox generalCB2;
}
}
```

Btw, this basically *is* an ArrayAdapter, which you could easily use instead.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question. I apologize in this, but I am relatively new to the android environment, so I am struggling a bit with all of this. Ultimately, I would like to have a dynamic ListView that has items that follow the row.xml layout and I am utterly lost. I have searched and searched everywhere, (even tried your suggestion) but cannot seem to get this working. I do have a workaround that involves a set number of players, which I don't want to limit users to a limitation like that, so maybe, I could have you help me out a bit if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: @Entralius I'd be happy to help and what you're seeking to do should be straight-forward. There is some contact info on my profile page. Also, accept my answer if you like it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will be emailing you from stephen.w.morgan88 prefix

Answer (score 1):

Why are you returning `null` in `getView` ?

Change it to `return convertView;`